# Fixing the fadeIn and fadeOut transitions overlapping

Tags: jquery

```
$('#btn').click(function(e) {    
    $('#minimalist, #typographic, #abstract').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('#all').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});

$('#btn2').click(function(e) {    
    $('#all, #typographic, #abstract').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('#minimalist').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});

$('#btn3').click(function(e) {    
    $('#all, #minimalist, #abstract').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('#typographic').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});

$('#btn4').click(function(e) {    
    $('#all, #typographic, #minimalist').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('#abstract').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

I am making a filtering system for categories.

I want the divs to overlap when fading in/out, instead it appears below the fading out div then shifts up into place.

http://jsfiddle.net/FgWHD/23/

Comment: `position: absolute;` on your fading in/out divs will get them to overlap as this pulls them out of the document flow, so they can sit on top of one another.

Comment: Awesome thanks! So I added some delays, but they seem to be kinda glitchy i.e. the delay times will fluctuate or sometimes not even delay at all. Any ideas on how to make this simpler and work fluently for what I'm trying to do? new version: (http://jsfiddle.net/FgWHD/29/)  @Ross

Answer (score 0):

try to add a class to links and to the divs, like this:

```
<div><a class="link" href="#" id="btn">All</a></div>
<div><a class="link" href="#" id="btn2">Minimalist</a></div>
<div><a class="link" href="#" id="btn3">Typographic</a></div>
<div><a class="link" href="#" id="btn4">Abstract</a></div>

<div class="x" id="all">All</div>
<div class="x" id="minimalist">Minimalist</div>
<div class="x" id="typographic">Typographic</div>
<div class="x" id="abstract">Abstract</div>
```

.. and use the position:absolute for the first item that is already displayed as Ross said:

```
#all {display:show; position:absolute;}
#minimalist {display:none;}
#typographic {display:none;}
#abstract {display:none;}
```

then you can use the .not() function to exclude the element matched by the class that
has to fadeIn/fadeOut :

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('.link').click( function() {
 var exclude = $(this).html().toLowerCase();
    $('.x').not('#' + exclude).fadeOut('slow', function() {
       $('#' + exclude).fadeIn('slow').css('position', 'absolute');
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/z4tH6/1/

I added a wrapping div around the items:

```
<div class="w">
  <div id="minimalist">Minimalist</div>
  <div id="typographic">Typographic</div>
  <div id="abstract">Abstract</div>
  <div id="all">All</div>
</div>
```

In the CSS, I used the "absolute position without positions" trick:

```
.w > div {
    position: absolute;
}

.w > div:last-child {
    position: static;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var id = '#'+$(this).text().toLowerCase();
    var $clicked = $(id);

    // ensure position: static by moving to the last position
    $clicked.appendTo( $clicked.parent() );

    $('.w > :not('+id+')').fadeOut( 1000, function(){
        $clicked.fadeIn( 1000 );
    });

    return false;
});
```